# Is "douze points" genuine French?

Tags: nombres, emprunts, substantivation

I've heard that "nul points", used in the context of [Eurovision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_at_the_Eurovision_Song_Contest), isn't genuine French:

> When a country finishes with a score of zero, it is often referred to
>   in English-language media as nul points, or sometimes nil points. The
>   correct French for "no points" is pas de points or zéro point, but
>   none of these phrases is used in the contest, as no-point scores are
>   not announced by the presenters.

Is "douze points" ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_in_the_Eurovision_Song_Contest_2016)) (or possibly [douze pointe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irelande_Douze_Pointe)?) genuine French?

> Australia came in 5th place with 196 points, and was awarded the
>   maximum 'douze points' by Austria and Sweden.

[Also](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote_au_Concours_Eurovision_de_la_chanson#1975-pr.C3.A9sent):

> [...] la victoire serait attribuée au pays ayant remporté le plus de «
>   douze points ».

Comment: Context for asking: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300015/are-there-any-fake-french-words-used-in-english

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Douze points*** is perfectly correct and genuine French, including in the sentence *la victoire serait attribuée au pays ayant remporté **le plus de « douze points »*** just like would be for example *Le gagnant sera celui qui aura mangé le plus de quatre-quart.*

Answer (score -1):

*Douze points* alone is good.

*Le plus de douze points* is incorrect. It would be like: *Le plus de des maisons.*

Ce qui est sous-entendu est: *Le plus de scores de douze points.*

Comment: There is nothing common between *le plus de "douze points"* and *le plus de des maisons*. They differ in two ways, (i) French conflates *\*de des* into a single *des* while it does nothing of the sort with *de douze* ; (ii) *"douze points"* is a kind of metalinguistic quotation and therefore has a special status in the construction...

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax . Vous avez raison, si on admet que les guillemets permettent d'inclure n'importe quoi. douze n'est pas nominalisé, à cause de points. On pourrait dire "le plus de score 12" d'où "le plus de 12".  Mais on devrait dire "chausser de la taille 42" .